# How to resolve ReflectionException Class orchestra.parser.xml does not exist

Tags: php, xml, laravel, parsing, ioc-container

I am trying to create an xml file using Orchestral/parser

> https://github.com/orchestral/parser

I correctly installed it and called it like this in my Controller:

```
use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Facade as XmlParser;

...

class Product extends Controller
{    
    public function createProduct()
   {
        $xml    = XmlParser::load("test.xml");
        $xmlR = $xml->parse([
            'id' => ['uses' => 'xmlR.id'],
        ]);
   }
}
```

But I get following error message:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 741: Class
>   orchestra.parser.xml does not exist

Thus I do not really understand what load means(in my case load("test.xml").

Comment: did you add the alias to the app config file? 'XmlParser' => Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Facade::class,

Comment: yep did that in config/app.php

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to refresh the autoload with command: composer dump-autoload

Comment: Ty for the answer, did that command but still get the same error message

Answer (score 1):

Your error clearly points that you did not set up the package in your **config/app.php** file (by listing the *provider* for the Orchestral XML Parser).

To resolve it, do add `Orchestra\Parser\XmlServiceProvider::class` to the list of providers in your *config/app.php* file as illustrated below:

> 'providers' => [
>
> // Other Laravel service providers
>
> Orchestra\Parser\XmlServiceProvider::class,
>
> ],

Answer (score 0):

clearing the cache fixed my problem:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```